# ADB finds no devices on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I think I've gone over just about every related thread on SO over this topic(there's a lot), but none seem to solve my issue.  Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and have attempted to get ADB working with an Android 6.0.1 Galaxy Note 5 and an Android 5.0.1 Galaxy S4.  Neither work as of right now.

For what it's worth, this did work last week, and I'm not entirely sure what changed.  There was a small systems update that included kernel firmware and udev updates, but not sure if that is the culprit.

Some basics I've tried:

- I've tried multiple USB cables and multiple ports
- Developer mode is on
- USB Debugging is turned on
- I have tried setting USB mode to Charging, PTP, and MTP
- I have restarted the adb server, and attempted to run it as root with no joy
- I have added the vendor ID in hex notation to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`
- I can view files via MTP, so the USB cable does appear to be working fine
- I have Revoked USB debugging authorizations
- I have downloaded the Android SDK directly from Google instead of using the one provided by Ubuntu
- I have tried both API version 24(which worked for me before) and 25

Running `adb devices` shows no results, like so:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

And `lsusb` does show my device:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
```

I have my udev rules setup.  Right now it's at 70 priority to overrule another set of udev rules that were overriding my permissions, but note that I have tried it at priority 51.

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

The permissions set by udev appear correct:

```
$ ls -lah /dev/bus/usb/001/029 
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root plugdev 189, 28 Dec 21 15:36 /dev/bus/usb/001/029
$ getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/029 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/029
# owner: root
# group: plugdev
user::rw-
user:mike:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::rw-
$ groups
mike adm dialout cdrom sudo audio plugdev
```

And for good measure, the phone does show up in `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg | tail
...
[18563.634381] usb 1-5.1.1: new high-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
[18563.739686] usb 1-5.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[18563.739689] usb 1-5.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[18563.739690] usb 1-5.1.1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[18563.739692] usb 1-5.1.1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[18563.739693] usb 1-5.1.1: SerialNumber: 05157df5xxxxxxxx
[18563.740895] cdc_acm 1-5.1.1:1.1: ttyACM1: USB ACM devic
```

And finally, a `udevadm test`:

```
$ sudo udevadm test /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-5.1.1
calling: test
version 229
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          229
file size:         7058303 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1762191 bytes
nodes              5296032 bytes
Load module index
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
timestamp of '/lib/udev/rules.d' changed
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/39-usbmuxd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-crda.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-apport.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/51-these-are-not-joysticks-rm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-hpmud.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-avrdude.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-boinc-client.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg2.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-inputattach.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-joystick.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-openobex.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-pcmcia.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-xdiagnose.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-gnome-bluetooth-rfkill.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-persistent-storage-android.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/66-snapd-autoimport.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/66-xorg-synaptics-quirks.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-xorg-vmmouse.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-debian-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-power-switch-proliant.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-u-d-c-gpu-detection.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-cinterion-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-huawei-net-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-mtk-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-nokia-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-pcmcia-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-platform-serial-whitelist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-qdl-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-simtech-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-telit-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-serial-adapters-greylist.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-x22x-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-graphics-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-debian-compat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-ifupdown.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-mm-candidate.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-snappy-assign.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/84-nm-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-brltty.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-keyboard-configuration.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-nm-unmanaged.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-fwupd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-libgpod.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-steam-controller-perms.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 196608 bytes tokens (16384 * 12 bytes), 31828 bytes strings
16161 strings (147268 bytes), 13390 de-duplicated (118212 bytes), 2772 trie nodes used
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'MSI'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'MSI'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:13
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:13
MODE 0664 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:41
GROUP 46 /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:10
MODE 0664 /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:10
PROGRAM '/usr/sbin/obex-check-device 04e8 6866' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-openobex.rules:3
starting '/usr/sbin/obex-check-device 04e8 6866'
Process '/usr/sbin/obex-check-device 04e8 6866' failed with exit code 1.
GROUP 46 /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules:1
MODE 0666 /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules:1
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules:49
RUN 'uaccess' /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules:15
handling device node '/dev/bus/usb/001/035', devnum=c189:34, mode=0666, uid=0, gid=46
preserve permissions /dev/bus/usb/001/035, 020666, uid=0, gid=46
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/189:34' to '../bus/usb/001/035'
created db file '/run/udev/data/c189:34' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-5/1-5.1/1-5.1.1'
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
COLORD_DEVICE=1
COLORD_KIND=camera
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/035
DEVNUM=035
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-5/1-5.1/1-5.1.1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
GPHOTO2_DRIVER=PTP
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_12_2-usb-0_5_1_1
ID_GPHOTO2=1
ID_MODEL=SAMSUNG_Android
ID_MODEL_ENC=SAMSUNG_Android
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III] (debugging mode)
ID_MODEL_ID=6866
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:12.2-usb-0:5.1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_12_2-usb-0_5_1_1
ID_REVISION=ffff
ID_SERIAL=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_05157df5b3b93107
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=05157df5b3b93107
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:060101:ff4201:
ID_VENDOR=SAMSUNG
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SAMSUNG
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
ID_VENDOR_ID=04e8
MAJOR=189
MINOR=34
PRODUCT=4e8/6866/ffff
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TAGS=:uaccess:seat:
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=20676851635
run: 'uaccess'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

I'm about at the end of rope here, so I'd appreciate any ideas or solutions.

Comment: Just making sure that 1) Are you running Chrome during your tests 2) Did you at some point test the Chrome Remote Debugging connection to your Android device and did not turn it off.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I am/was running Chrome, yes.  For a quick test I shut it down, restarted the adb server, and tried again with no luck.  I have not been using Chrome Remote Debugging, intentionally, anyway.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Small correction.  I have used chrome remote debugging in the past from a different machine.  I made sure to shut that machine's Chrome down as well and ran the same test, no luck.

Comment: I have same problem with a Wileyfox Swift.
One interesting thing is "invalid key/value pair in file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android" when I do sudo service udev status
BTW I couldn't get udevadm to work. There is a directory /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-5.1:1.1: and a directory /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-0:1.0:. But using the former gave unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.1/1-5.1:1.1'
and similar for using the latter.

Comment: Got rid of "invalid key/value pair..." error message by amending the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules to change the funny double quote symbol that you had: confirmed by using od -c /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules. Content of file is now:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2970", ATTR{idProduct}=="2282", MODE="0666"
udevadm now works using udevadm info -q all -n /dev/bus/usb/001/015.
However, adb devices still shows no devices!